# augmented dickey fuller Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to employ Dickey-Fuller test in Matlab, but instead of this test in Matlab exist only augmented Dickey-Fuller test (adftest). There is the explanation in Matlab help (https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/adftest.html) that we can "Conduct a Dickey-Fuller Test Without Augmentation" what is "Test a time series for a unit root using the default autoregression model without augmented difference terms." Does it mean that this case is Dickey-Fuller test (without augmentation) for which I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Dickey-Fuller and DF with Augmentation (ADF) is in the number of difference terms. To make things clearer, I'll assume no drift and no trend-stationarity.

According to Matlab documentation, ADF model looks as follows: [image].

According to Wikipedia, Dickey Fuller is [image]. As you can see, there are no diff terms here.

To see an example, first run Dickey Fuller:

```
rng(1); % for reproduction
x = rand(100, 1); % generate 100 random numbers (null hypothesis shouldn't be rejected)
[h,pValue,stat,cValue,reg] = adftest(x);
reg.coeff
```

Returns:

```
0.7089
```

For ADF with (say) 2 difference terms:

```
[h,pValue,stat,cValue,reg] = adftest(x, 'lags', 0:2);
reg.coeff(3)
```

Returns 3 coefficients:

```
0.9087
-0.7067
-0.4021
```

You can test for yourself that the zero hypothesis is not rejected in either case as you would expect.